# Find currently opened dialog in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, dialog, swt, eclipse-rcp

My question is: I want to find the name of currently opened dialog(being displayed on top of all views) and finally reload it. Can anyone guide me for this ?

Comment: Thank you Baz for the comment. Indeed, I used the code org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell().getText() and equivalently org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getActiveShell().getText() too. But both of these codes produced same output i.e. the name of dialog.

Comment: never mind! Baz. You are always welcome to do so.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dialog is focused, you can access its `Shell` via:

```
Shell active = Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell();
String title = active.getText();
```

If you are using Eclipse RCP, you can do the same by using:

```
Shell active = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getActiveShell();
String title = active.getText();
```